# easiest way to get continual unit tests running locally with visual alerts, with xUnit for C#/VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, continuous-integration, xunit.net

I'm currently using MSTest in VS2008 for unit tests, but I am looking at going to xUnit.net.

Question - What would be the easiest way to get my unit tests running continually locally (on my PC) and with some sort of visual alert of pass / # of fails.

i.e. similar to what we do in Ruby on Rails with autospec.

THanks

PS Intersested in hearing of the simplest open source option too.

Answer (score 1):

You should also ask this on http://xunit.codeplex.com/Thread/List.aspx

There's an xUnit GUI runner and it has an auto-reload when DLLs get touched.

The missing bit is the auto-rerun of the last of executed tests when that happens. The minute we have that, you're just a Shift F6 (compile current project) away from waht you want.

The xunit.net guys are normally quite responsive, and avote on [my] http://xunit.codeplex.com/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=8832 would help.

Regarding your other comment - I really believe xUnit.net is worth your effort using. You won't look back.

Answer (score 0):

[Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)'s test runner runs within VS, can run just a single test or a whole suite, and appears to support [xUnit with a plugin](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/plugins/).

Comment: In this casewould you recommend sticking with MSTest, ie if going with resharper?

Comment: can't see a way in Reshaper to do what my question here poses